# pandas.DataFrame returns Series not a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a series of images. I read them first and store in the list then I convert them to dataframe and finally I would like to implement Isomap. When I read images (I have 84 of them) I get 84x2303 dataframe of objects. Now each object by itself also looks like a dataframe. I am wondering how to convert all of it to_numeric so I can use Isomap on it and then plot it. 
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import misc
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from sklearn import manifold

samples = []

path = 'Datasets/ALOI/32/*.png'
files = glob.glob(path)

for name in files:

    img = misc.imread(name)
    img = img[::2, ::2]
    x = (img/255.0).reshape(-1,3)
    samples.append(x)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(samples)

print df.dtypes

print df.shape
```

Thanks!